# Why vue(v-on) does not finds my function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am completely new to Vue (and JS), so please forgive me "stupid" questions.

In my Vue-Pet-Project I have got a self written class module Sudoku. In this I want to search for results with backtracking. Now Vue recognized the click on the "startSearch" button, but tells me:

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler:
>   "ReferenceError: backtrack is not defined"
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
>           warn @ vue.esm.js?a026:628 logError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1893 globalHandleError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1888
>   handleError @ vue.esm.js?a026:1848 invokeWithErrorHandling @
>   vue.esm.js?a026:1871 invoker @ vue.esm.js?a026:2188 original._wrapper
>   @ vue.esm.js?a026:7559 vue.esm.js?a026:1897 ReferenceError: backtrack
>   is not defined
>       at Sudoku.search (sudoku.js?9ece:4)
>       at VueComponent.startSearchSolutions (App.vue?9c43:74)
>       at click (App.vue?88bf:69)
>       at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js?a026:1863)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.esm.js?a026:2188)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.original._wrapper (vue.esm.js?a026:7559)

though this function is declared. Here the code of my class:

```
module.exports.Sudoku = class Sudoku
{
    [...]

search()
{
  console.log("search started")
  let results = []

  backtrack(this.myNumbers,0,0,results)

  return results
}

backtrack(testNumbers,x,y,results)
{
  console.log("start backtrack")

  //TODO: yet much to do...

  if(x===9 && y===9)
  {
    results.push([...testNumbers])
    console.log("result added")
  }
}
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this.backtrack instant of just backtrack for reference backtrack method.

```js
module.exports.Sudoku = class Sudoku
{
    [...]

search()
{
  console.log("search started")
  let results = []
  
  //use this for reference backtrack method. Heir this is the Sudoku class itself
  this.backtrack(this.myNumbers,0,0,results)

  return results
}

backtrack(testNumbers,x,y,results)
{
  console.log("start backtrack")

  //TODO: yet much to do...

  if(x===9 && y===9)
  {
    results.push([...testNumbers])
    console.log("result added")
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Did not see that! Thank you!